# Allow optional trailing slash when using optional parameter

Tags: php, slim

Given this path: `/page(/:pageID)`, how can I allow the following variations:

- `/page` and `/page/` (even if the pageID part is missing.
- `/page/1` and `/page/1/`

Thank you.

Comment: What is the relationship between the PHP language and your question? What is your current PHP code?

Comment: Slim is a PHP Framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must define your route this way:

```
$app->get('/page(/:id/?)', function ($id = NULL) use ($app) {
    ; // your code
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer provided by @inst would not work here (Slim 2.0.0 running on XAMPP): /page/ gives out a 404.

This works in all four cases though:

```
$app->get('/page(/)(:id/?)', function ($id = NULL) use ($app) {
  echo 'success';
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain the `('/page(/)(:id/?)'` part. Regards

Comment: I have posted a question for [the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550041/slim-optional-parameter-issue) I have.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Parameters), optional segments may be unstable depending on the usage. For example, with the answer given by Fabien Snauwaert, and the following routes:

```
/:controller(/)(:action(/)(:overflow+/?))
/:controller(/)(:action(/:overflow+/?))
```

If not filled all the arguments, when obtain param values, these will be in a position to the right, resulting in `action == controller` and `overflow == action`.

To prevent this, a simple solution is to put the optional slash at the end of the route.

```
/:controller(/:action(/:overflow+))/?
/:controller(/:action(/:overflow+))(/)
```

And it is more readable, isn't it?

I can not comment on others answers, so I write here a detail concerning the Igor response.

One "problem" with this approach is that if the user tries to access a page that does not exist, and also do with a trailing slash, will be a 301 redirect to display a 404 page. Maybe a little weird.

Answer (score 1):

I found this way to achive this with Apache mod_rewrite enabled. Snippet of `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

An example for Slim V3:

```
/[{param1:[0-9]+}[/[{param2:[0-9]+}[/]]]]
```

This will cover:

```
/
/1
/1/
/1/2
/1/2/
```