# SLIM Optional Parameter Issue

Tags: php, restful-url, slim

I trying to achieve something like this in Slim PHP:

> page/p1/p2/p3/p4

I want that If I leave out params from the right(obviously) then I want to do my stuff based on whatever params I've received.

```php
    $app->get('/page(/)(:p1/?)(:p2/?)(:p3/?)(:p4/?)', 
        function ($p1 = null, $p2 = null, $p3 = null, $p4 = null) {
            print empty($p1)? : '' . "p1: $p1/<br/>";
            print empty($p2)? : '' . "p2: $p2/<br/>";
            print empty($p3)? : '' . "p3: $p3/<br/>";
            print empty($p4)? : '' . "id: $p4<br/>";
    });
```

Everything works as expected but the problem is whenever i remove a param from the end, it prints `1` for every param I remove.
why is it doing so?
what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you omitted the second part of the ternary (what should print if the test statement returns `true`), the ternary statement returns what the test expression evaluates to. That result is then printed out.

When you omit the last parameter in the route, the test expression results to `true`, but since you do not define what to do in this case, `true` is returned and `1` is printed out.

Try this instead:

```
$app->get('/page(/)(:p1/?)(:p2/?)(:p3/?)(:p4/?)', 
    function ($p1 = null, $p2 = null, $p3 = null, $p4 = null) {
        print empty($p1)? "" : '' . "p1: $p1/<br/>";
        print empty($p2)? "" : '' . "p2: $p2/<br/>";
        print empty($p3)? "" : '' . "p3: $p3/<br/>";
        print empty($p4)? "" : '' . "id: $p4<br/>";
});
```

Now the script knows what to do should one of those `empty()` expressions return true -- print an empty string.